# Error Page Not Shown - when wrong context root is given

Tags: custom-error-pages

I have one application deployed on JBoss 7.x under the context root "helloworld" that has:

welcome.jsp and error.jsp.

The custom error page specified in the web.xml DD as:

```
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

when I access the page as:

```
http://localhost:8080/helloworld/welcome.jsp
```

I get the page as expected.

```
http://localhost:8080/helloworld/welcome_does_not_exist.jsp
```

takes me to:

```
http://localhost:8080/helloworld/error.jsp
```

however

```
http://localhost:8080/helloworld_DOES_NOT_EXIST/welcome.jsp
```

does not take me to the custom error page but shows:

> ========
>   HTTP Status 404 - /helloworld_DOES_NOT_EXIST/welcome.jsp
>
> type Status report
>
> message /helloworld_DOES_NOT_EXIST/welcome.jsp
>
> description The requested resource (/helloworld_DOES_NOT_EXIST/welcome.jsp) 
>   is not available.
>
> JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final
>
> =========

Could you please let me know how to set the error page so that even when we specify the wrong context root we get the custom error page?

Thanks.